# Select on select join on codeigniter query builder

Tags: mysql, codeigniter

It is possible to generate the following query by CI Query Builder class ?

```
SELECT 
dept, 
count(nik) * 3 * (
    SELECT 
    count(distinct(tanggal)) as jday 
    FROM `tab_detail_absen` 
    where tanggal between '2021-05-31' and '2021-06-04'
) as jabs 
FROM `tab_member_meet` 
group by dept
) a left join 
(
SELECT 
left(kode_org,3) as dept, 
count(status) as jth  
FROM `tab_detail_absen` 
where 
status = 'T' and 
keterangan = '' and 
tanggal between '2021-05-31' and '2021-06-04'
group by dept
) b on a.dept = b.dept left join 
(
 select 
    left(kode_org,3) as dept, 
    count(nik) as jentry 
    from tab_detail_absen 
    where tanggal 
    between '2021-05-31' and '2021-06-04' 
    group by left(kode_org,3)   
) c on a.dept = c.dept
```

Comment: what version of CI?

Comment: It might be possible but why would you want to abstract it out? IMHO such a large complex query would be harder to troubleshoot in CI